# Include 3rd party DLLs in a NuGet package generated from a VS csproj

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-spec

I'm trying to create a NuGet package from a VS 2017 project that contains a reference to a 3rd party DLL (Kendo.mvc.dll).  No matter what I try, I can't get `nuget pack` to automatically include that DLL in my NuGet package's lib folder.

I originally created the `.nuspec` file from the command line with the command `nuget spec [project's name and path].csproj`.  I then tweaked the settings of that file which resulted in this .nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>our names</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>the description</description>
    <releaseNotes>First release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>entity-framework-6 mvc5</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I then used `nuget pack` to create the package, which resulted in this:

[image: Package contents showing no 3rd party DLL was included]

From what I've read in the documentation ([MS Docs - Creating NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-visual-studio-project)) I was expecting `nuget pack` to automatically include any non-nuget-sourced DLLs referenced in the project in the package, but that's not happening?

I've tried the following to see if it makes any difference, all to no avail:

- Adding a `lib` folder to the root of my project and putting the DLL in there (and experimented a bit with changing the Build Action and Copy to Output Directory settings).  That created a lib folder under the Content folder in the NuGet package, rather than adding the DLL to the same `lib` folder that contains the assembly's DLL.  I did that because [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory) talk about a convention based file structure.
- Referencing the DLL from a folder in C:\Program Files and setting the Copy Local property for the DLL to true in the Properties

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466844/nuget-and-third-party-dlls) talks about adding a separate element for the 3rd party DLL which I'm guessing refers to adding the files explicitly in the `.nuspec` file before generating the package, e.g.

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\Kendo.Mvc.???" target="lib\net461" />
  </files>
```

That does work, but shouldn't this be added automatically if it's needed when generating a `.nuspec` file from a `csproj` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but shouldn't this be added automatically if it's needed when generating a .nuspec file from a csproj file?

Yes, the non-nuget-sourced DLLs were not added automatically by default when generating a `.nuspec` file from a `.csproj` file.

When we generate the `.nuspec` file from a `.csproj` file, the `.nuspec` only includes the basic info, for example, Title, Description, and so on. You can get this info from Assembly Information, Properties->Application-> Assembly Information:

[image]

**But it does not include the 3rd party DLL by default.**

So, in order to include third party DLLs, we need manually add the files explicitly in the `.nuspec` file, jusy like what you did.

Check [Create nuget package from dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls) for more details.

BTW, if the 3rd party DLL is nuget-sourced DLLs referenced in the project, you can use the parameter `-IncludeReferencedProjects` to add it automatically when generating a .nuspec file from a csproj file.

Document: [pack command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack#options)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do it through Visual Studio or dotnet, then you can edit your csproj file, add an ItemGroup to include the dlls as below: This will pack the other dlls along with your current project dll in the nuget package.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="<path to other dll>">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: $(TargetFramework) does not working for VS2022. It just place my external dll outside the lib folder. I had to explicitly put <PackagePath>lib\net6.0</PackagePath>. And if my project multitarget, I need to have another similar block of <Content>...</Content> with the other target framework sepcified